# AJAX failing to upload blob image

Tags: ajax

I have a problem with uploading a blob using ajax. I have tried many options and they are not working.

I must say that the same variables (albeit with different names) work when using php in the standard sense but not when using ajax.

Please help

The ajax code is:

```
$(function() {

$("#upload").click(function() {
  // validate and process form here   

  var username = $("input#username").val();

    var title = $("input#title").val();

    var image = $("#image").get(0).files.item(0);

    var information = tinymce.get('blogcontent').getContent();

     var dt = new Date();

//   variable for blog date and time  
   var dateandtime = dt.toLocaleString();

var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&title=' + title + '&image=' + image + '&information=' + information + '&dateandtime=' + dateandtime;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "functions/insertblogpost.php",
data: dataString,
success: function() {

  $('#writeblog').html("<div id='message'></div>");
  $('#message').html("<h2>User account created!</h2>")
  .append("<p>Please go back to login.</p>")
  .hide()
  .fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $('#message').append("<a href='../../Mobileapptemplate.php'>Back</a>");
  });
}
});


return false;

  });
});
```

And the php script is:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database);

        $username = $_POST[ 'username' ];

        $blogTitle = $_POST["title"];

        $blogContent = $_POST["information"];

        $blogpicturename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

        $blogpicdata = mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

        $blogpictype = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        $dateAndTime = $_POST["dateandtime"];
        $result =  "INSERT INTO ct5006ho_users.$username ( postnumber, user, title, 
        picturename, picture, blogpost, dateandtime ) VALUES ( '', '$username', '$blogTitle','$blogpicturename', 
        '$blogpicdata','$blogContent', '$dateAndTime');";

//if (
mysqli_query($connection, $result);
```

The connection IS established fine and all other data uploads to the phpmyadmin created database. I have omitted those details from the code.

Comment: var image = $("#image").get(0).files.item(0);

Comment: var image = $("#image").get(0).files.item(0);
was actually originally
    var image = $("#image").val();

Neither option works

Comment: As many examples were using different functions, I struggled particularly with tinymce data transfer and the time variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

$(function() {

```
$("#upload").click(function() {
  // validate and process form here   
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var form = $('form')[0]; // 
    var formData = new FormData(form);


 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "functions/insertblogpost.php",
 data: formData, // Data sent to server, a se
 contentType: false,       
  cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
 processData:false,
success: function() { ....................
```

If anybody has a similar issue please use this experience to help you.

Note - tinyMCE.triggerSave(); - sends the tinyMCE data. and this was my original issue with the  - data: formData,

Ah well, shoot me down for asking!